# LINQ query is not returning the required details

Tags: entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have a table "employee" which has the columns  (id, emp_name, emp_email, mngr_email) also I have another table "mngr"
which has the columns(id, email). I want to get the employee records and mngr records for an employee. Ultimately mngr also an employee, so I want the mngr name is also in the records. Please help me to get the query.

```
var rec = (from em in Context.employee
   join mn in .Context.mngr on em.id equals mn.id
   where em.id == 1
   select new Records()
   {

       Name = em.name,
       emp_email = em.email,
       mngr_email = mn.email,
       mngr_name = ---?,
       mngr_id = mn.id

   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model could be better designed, but based on what you have you need to join employee a 2nd time. You link by email, so:

```
var rec= (from em in Context.employee
          left join me in Context.employee on me.email equals em.mngr_email 
          where em.id==1
          select new Records()
          {
              Name = em.name,
              emp_email= em.email,
              mngr_email = em.mngr_email,
              mngr_name = me.name,
              mngr_id = me.id
          }).ToList();
```

Here is a more straight forward approach to employee/manager self referencing relationship: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206410/How-to-Configure-a-Self-Referencing-Entity-in-Code